# how to delete the specific item in the document directory ios objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdocumentdirectory

I want remove specific item from `DocumentDirectory` i.e I have 50 objects in the `DocumentDirectory` and i want to remove the 5 different elements from it. I used following code to get the `DocumentDirectory` objects.

```
NSURL *vedioURL;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

NSArray *filePathsArray = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] subpathsOfDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory  error:nil];

NSLog(@"files array %@", filePathsArray);
```

can any one Help me out to solve this problem

Comment: Can you specify which object you want to delete?

Comment: Are you want remove specific video file?

Comment: not video  files this  items i have to remove FileName, "Name.png", "Testapp.sqlite", "Testapp.sqlite-shm", "Testapp.sqlite-wal", "image_name" –

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try like this way

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
if (filePathsArray.count >= 6) {
    for (NSInteger i=filePathsArray.count-6; i < filePathsArray.count; i++) {
        NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[filePathsArray objectAtIndex:i]];
        if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath])  {
           NSError *error;
            if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"Delete error: %@", error);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you know which object you want to delete?

Comment: this are the files i have in the document directory  
"2016-07-27-11-48-11-0.MOV","2016-07-27-14-10-25-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-14-10-40-0.MOV","2016-07-27-14-47-26-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-17-00-51-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-17-14-03-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-18-29-08-0.MOV","2016-07-27-18-35-27-0.MOV" "2016-07-28-09-56-18-0.MOV""2016-07-28-16-47-40-0.MOV", "2016-07-28-16-52-46-0.MOV","2016-07-29-17-00-12-0.MOV", "2016-08-04-10-59-01-0.MOV", FileName, "Name.png", "Testapp.sqlite", "Testapp.sqlite-shm", "Testapp.sqlite-wal", "image_name" –  i have to delete last 6 elements

Comment: @SatheeshkumarNaidu You want to remove last 6 object from array right?

Comment: Check my edit to delete last 6 object from your array.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following approach

```
NSString *path = nil;
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
path = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR DIR"];
path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR FILE"];
NSError *error;
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:path])     
{
    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:path error:&error])   //Delete it
    {
        NSLog(@"Delete file error: %@", error);
    }
}
```

Comment: path = [paths[0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR DIR"]; which directory i have to give    path = [path stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YOUR FILE"]; which file i have to give

Comment: "2016-07-27-11-48-11-0.MOV","2016-07-27-14-10-25-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-14-10-40-0.MOV","2016-07-27-14-47-26-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-17-00-51-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-17-14-03-0.MOV", "2016-07-27-18-29-08-0.MOV","2016-07-27-18-35-27-0.MOV"  "2016-07-28-09-56-18-0.MOV""2016-07-28-16-47-40-0.MOV", "2016-07-28-16-52-46-0.MOV","2016-07-29-17-00-12-0.MOV", "2016-08-04-10-59-01-0.MOV",
    FileName,
    "Name.png",
    "Testapp.sqlite",
    "Testapp.sqlite-shm",
    "Testapp.sqlite-wal",
    "image_name"

Comment: i want to delete last 6 files

Comment: Sorry for late reply as it has been answered by @NDoc earlier.

Comment: no problem.i have other doubt.i want play this video in the collection view cell and the collection is having other 15 more images i want add the video as the 16 th element

Comment: Please post a new question for it.